# Facebook App Submission with an API

Tags: facebook, cordova

I have a cordova iOS app that requests permissions (during account creation) and the access_token is stored in our DB for later use.  When a user "posts" through the iOS app, the post data is sent to our API where we process, store, and finally post on behalf of the user to the users wall on Facebook.

I am having issues with the App Submission process because they are requiring a Facebook login because I have listed the API url as a Website Site URL under the app settings of the Facebook app.  Is there another place I can list the API url to allow Facebook to allow requests/posts from the URL, or do I need to specify in my submission comments that the website URL is strictly an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James, the app permissions and login review process is quite clear on this. If your app uses any of the permissions and acts on behalf of the user, then the review team needs to test out the app behavior end-to-end.
And since your app requires that permission (publish_actions), it's only natural they need to go through the Login dialog in order to provide approval for the same. If I am missing something here, let me know. But otherwise, I think the requirement is clear.